# ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event

Tags: pipelines, dynamic-placeholder

When trying to save changes to page layout in Experience Editor, errors appear and the page does not save.

The details in the logs showed:

```
System.Xml.XmlException  Message[1]: Root element is missing.
```

I could see this was an issue to do with `DyanamicPlaceholdersDebug.OnItemSaved` failing but wasn't sure what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some debugging by overriding the pipeline with my own I figured out this was due to an empty _renderings field. The _finalrenderings field was populated but the _renderings field wasn't and the Dynamic Placeholders save pipeline expects it to be.

[image]

This was due to a miss-configuration on the standard values of the template for the page. Updating this so that the standard values set a layout and components on the shared layout instead of the final layout solved the problem.